# Dependent dropdown for country and state in yii 1.13

Tags: php, yii

I had created two database tables as,

1. Country
2. State

In Country table i had countryid & cname field. In State table i had state_id, state_name & country_cid.

Now i need to make a dependent dropdown i.e. when i select country dropdown box, then the particular state for that country should be displayed. I had done below coding. But it displays only country and not displays state.

This is in **views/sample/register.php** file.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'countryid'); 
    $opts = CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(),'countryid','cname');
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',$opts,
        array(
                'prompt'=>'Select Country',
                'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('SampleController/dynamicSubcategory'),
                 array('coountry_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                 'dataType' => 'JSON',
                 'success'=>'js:function(data)'
                 . '{'
                 .  'var html="<option value=>-----Select city-----</option>";'
                 .  '$.each(data,function(i,obj)'
                 .  '{'
                 .      'html+="<option value=\'"+obj.id+"\'>"+obj.name+"</option>";'
                 .  '});'
                 .  '$("#state_id").html(html);'
                 .  '}'
                 )));
    echo $form->error($model,'country_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state_id'); 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('state_id','', array());
    echo $form->error($model,'state_id'); ?>
</div>
```

This is in **controllers/SampleController.php** file

```
public function actiondynamicSubcategory()
{
        $countryId=$_POST['coountry_id'];
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select=array('state_id,state_name');
        $criteria->condition='country_cid='.$countryId;
        $criteria->order='state_name';
        $cityAry= State::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $ary=array();
        foreach($cityAry as $i=>$obj)
        {
            $ary[$i]['state_id']=$obj->id;
            $ary[$i]['state_name']=$obj->name;            
        }
        echo json_encode($ary);
}
```

I had created Country model & State model. I had analyzed many sites. But i can't get right. Please anybody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.

This is in **views/sample/register.php** file

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'country'); 
    $opts = CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(),'countryid','cname');
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country_id',$opts,
        array(
                'prompt'=>'Select Country',
                'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST', 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('Sample/dynamicSubcategory'),
                'update'=>'#state_name',
                'data'=>array('country_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                 )));
    echo $form->error($model,'country_id'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state_id');
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('state_name','', array(), array(
        'prompt'=>'Select State'

        ));
    echo $form->error($model,'state_id'); ?>
</div>
```

This is in **controllers/SampleController.php** file

```
public function actiondynamicSubcategory()
{
    $data=State::model()->findAll('country_cid=:countryid', 
    array(':countryid'=>(int) $_POST['country_id']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'state_id','state_name');

    echo "<option value=''>Select State</option>";
    foreach($data as $value=>$state_name)
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($state_name),true);
}
```

This code works fine for dependent dropdown in yii

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code which I have used in one of my projects -

```
**Code in the view file :** 
<?php $arrOptionsCountry = array('prompt'=>'Select Country','ajax'=> array('type'=>'POST','url' => ApplicationConfig::getURL('', 'site','SearchValueStates'),'update'=>'#Airports_state','beforeSend'=>'stateLoading'));

echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country',$arrCountryList,$arrOptionsCountry,array('class'=>'span11 customDropdown1_select')); 

$arrOptionsState = array('prompt'=>'Select State','ajax'=> array('type'=>'POST','url' => ApplicationConfig::getURL('', 'site', 'SearchValueCities'),'update'=>'#station_name','beforeSend'=>'cityLoading'));

echo $form->dropDownList($model,'state',$arrStatesList,$arrOptionsState); 

echo $form->dropDownList($model,'city',$arrCityList);
?> 


 **Site Controller :** 
    public function actionSearchValueStates()
    { 
    $arrParam =array();
    if(isset($_POST['Airports']['country']))
    {   
        $Term = $_POST['Airports']['country'] ;

        $case = "STATE-LIST";
        $prompt = "Select State";

        $arrParam['id'] = isset($Term)?$Term:null ;
        $data = States::getList($case,$arrParam);

           $data = CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');

           echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>''),$prompt,true);
           foreach($data as $value=>$name)
           {
                echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name));
           }    
    }

       Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. It displays the ajax, post etc. in my drop down box which is entered in the 1st line of the code